# how do i make my images slide in and out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ive created a slideshow on my page but instead of my pictures just changing i want them to have an effect of sliding in and out. any suggestions?

```
<div class="main-container2">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <img src="c:/users/saleh/desktop/Abid/pics/limo_black.jpg" name="slide">
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var step = 1
    function slideit(){
        if (!document.images)
            return
        document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
        if (step<3);
            step++;
        else
            step = 1;
        setTimeout("slideit()",2500);

        }
        slideit();
</script>;
```

Comment: @SalehK there is a lot of stuff when Googling `javascript make images slide in and out`. Check it out, it should provide you with all the info you need

Comment: @Niet whats wrong with eval? im new to javascript and got most of this off google. how do i make it better?

Comment: Let's start with something simple: Do you even know what eval does?

Comment: i think so eval will execute an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just playing around...

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/IzuFaPOP/3/edit)

Having images the exact width as `#slideshow`:

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="image1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="image2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="image3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

All you need is:

```
#slideshow{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0;
}
```

and:

```
var $s = $('#slideshow'),
    $i=$('img', $s),
    N=$i.length+1,
    C=0;  

$i.eq(0).clone().appendTo($s);

function anim(){
    if(C===N){$s.scrollLeft(0);C=0;}
    $s.delay(C?2000:0).animate({ scrollLeft: ++C*300 },400, anim);  
}
anim(); // Use this fn 'call' wherever you want to start the animation.
```

What this does is an **infinite** slide movement achieved by simply cloning and appending the first image to the end,

this way (after we register that incremented variable C reached the total number of images) we can immediately set scrollLeft to `0` making the *reset* unnoticeable to the eye.

The loop is achieved by simply recalling our function `anim` in the `.animate()` callback.

---

[**If you want it to stop on mouseenter:**](http://jsbin.com/IzuFaPOP/4/edit)

```
var $s = $('#slideshow'),
    $i = $('img', $s),
    N = $i.length+1,
    C = 0,
    m = 0; // flag for mouseover

$i.eq(0).clone().appendTo($s);

function anim(){
    if(m)return setTimeout(anim, 200);
    if(C===N){$s.scrollLeft(0);C=0;}
    $s.delay(C?2000:0).animate({ scrollLeft: ++C*300 },400, anim);  
}anim();

$s.hover(function(){ m^=1; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save yourself some time and use Bootstrap. It has this all implemented using JQuery.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Alternative slide wrapper -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">  

    <div class="item active">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="contributor">
          <img class="image-circle" src="..." alt>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

A note regarding the alternative slide wrapper. When I was implementing the Bootstrap3 carousel I found that it didn't work, but if I used the Bootstrap2 slide wrappers it did. No rhyme or reason to it but that's what I found. As for where you'd put the `carousel-caption` div in this secondary layout. I haven't the foggiest, probably within the container and not the contributor.

The indicators you'll see at the link aren't necessary cause they're generated by the JavaScript initializer. Which is initiated like this.

```
$(".carousel").carousel({
    interval: false
});
```

But you needn't add any arguments for your purposes. I set `interval:false` on mine so it didn't auto-scroll but it sounds like you may want this behaviour. So all you need is `.carousel();` and you can initialize by id or class. I'm initializing by class.

On a totally different note I'd suggest installing an Apache host on your machine so that your code is ready to publish. Also using windows file links like that isn't good practice and can cause all sorts of issues while you're developing especially when including CSS files. At least use relative links to the directory you're running the page from.

My personal preference is a Linux OS with Apache natively installed using SublimeText and Chrome for editing and testing respectively. But that's my preference, mainly because most of my pages are built using PHP and MySQL integration.